# Trouble to understand PDO bindValue and execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Recently i started learning PDO, and i fetch a trouble to understand the behavior of bindValue and direct execute with array.

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM category WHERE `category_name`=?');
$statement->bindValue(1, 'Swimwear'); // It's okey
$statement->execute();

//direct execute with array
$statement->execute(array('Swimwear')); // It's also okey
```

But the real problem is why i don't have to use like?

```
$statement->execute(array(1 => 'Swimwear')); // It's not okey, Not working
```

Answer (score 2):

`$statement->execute(array(1 => 'Swimwear'));` does not work, because the value should be in index 0, not 1. When using this syntax, correct code would be:

```
$statement->execute(array(0 => 'Swimwear'));
```

Though I don't see any point using such complicated syntax over `array('Swimwear')`.

Comment: You are right, But i am unaware of this difference that the BindValue start indexing from 1, I now about the array which is started from 0.

Comment: Glad to see you again giving correct answers as usual.

Answer (score 0):

With PDO you have three ways of adding placeholder values.

You can add them in individually with `bindValue`.

You can add them in a simple array.

You can add them with an associative array *if* you have named them.

So to get that style to work you need to add a name to the prepared statement and also to the array passed to `execute`:

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM category WHERE `category_name`=:category');
$statement->execute(array(':category' => 'Swimwear'));
```

There is no placeholder named `1` so this wasn't working.

The [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) function takes 1-indexed values which is why the `bindValue(1, 'Swimwear')` call works. This is an exception to the usual 0-indexed rule of programming.

To make it work with the associative style you'll need to call it this way:

```
$statement->execute(array(0 => 'Swimwear'));
```

Comment: I use **`category_name`=?** not the named one.

Comment: Those are un-named, so you should use the simple array style to populate those. I find named placeholders are much harder to mess up, you won't mistakenly reverse the order of some values, something that can be very easy to do if you have a dozen columns to populate.

Comment: But the BindValue works fine with un-named like: `$statement->bindValue(1, 'Swimwear');`

Comment: When using `category_name=?` it is expecting to find the element from index **0**, not 1.

Comment: @1615903, But how this `$statement->bindValue(1, 'Swimwear');` working??

Comment: @1615903 Also true.

Comment: @RivnatNasah As always, read [the documentation on `bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) which states it's 1-indexed. Regular arrays are not. This just one of the quirks of PDO.

Comment: So you mean the BIndValue start indexing from 1 and regular array from 0??

Comment: @RivnatNasah Precisely. It's 1-indexed, arrays are 0-indexed.

Comment: So this is the main point of my question. I need to use `0+` for array and `1+` for BIndValue...

Comment: There's really no point in using `array(0 => 'Swimwear')` instead of `array('Swimwear')`, but if you really, really want to, give it a try.

Comment: I already got my answer, If you make the major change (It's 1-indexed, arrays are 0-indexed related things) than i can mark your answer.

Comment: Note added accordingly.